# Forced to update certificate .pem in android app

Tags: android, ssl

```
 public static SSLContext getSSL() {
        try {
            CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
            AssetManager assetManager = App.getAppContext()
                    .getAssets();
            InputStream caInput = assetManager.open("cert.pem");
            java.security.cert.X509Certificate ca = null;
            try {
                ca = (java.security.cert.X509Certificate) cf
                        .generateCertificate(caInput);
            } catch (Exception er) {

            } finally {
                caInput.close();
            }
            String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
            keyStore.load(null, null);
            keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca",
                    ca);
            String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
            TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory
                    .getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
            tmf.init(keyStore);
            SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
            return context;
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

So I am using that function, and it was working when I call the following function

```
 ((HttpsURLConnection) conn).setSSLSocketFactory(Common
                                    .getSSL().getSocketFactory()
```

HOWEVER the issue arrised when my client informed me of new certificate, and that I need to update my app with new certificate for it work.My question here is, how is right way to go about this? Why do I need to update certificate in app everytime? I have it in asssets folder. Should I Download certificate from somewhere everytime? People who do not update app , will not work with the app because of old certificate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you throw just some code into the question without explanation of what it is exactly used for. My guess is that you use it to treat a specific self-signed certificate given to you by your client as trusted. This means that if the certificate changes on the server side the client side (i.e. the app or at least the cert.pem file used by the app) needs to be updated.

The common way to deal with certificate updates is not using self-signed certificates in the first place. Instead certificates issued by a public CA should be used because then application will accept any certificate issued by any of CA in the builtin trust store, provided that the certificate is issued for the expected site. This way even frequent certificate updates are no problem and the app does not need to be updated to accept the new certificate.

I recommend that you talk to your client to move away from self-signed certificates to the established method of using public certificates. These are not costly, i.e. CA's like Let's Encrypt offer these for free.

Comment: some of our server is auto-updates SSL certificate every 3 month for security reason, so i have to update this certificate in my application, and re-upload in google play store,

Comment: so how can i auto update SSL certificate in my android app?

Comment: @GauravMandlik: *"so i have to update this certificate in my application, and re-upload in google play store"* - there is no need to update the certificate in your application if you don't base the trust in the certificate but instead in the issuer CA or the public key used in all certificates.